# Python script using shutil.copy creating empty files during start up only

Tags: python, shutil

I have a script which runs at boot in rc3.d which copies files from one directory to another.  If I run this from the command line it copies them as expected.  When it runs during a reboot it creates an empty file.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
COMP = ["ex","et"]
for COMPs in COMP:
    shutil.copy('/home/etc/init.d/'+COMPs+'','/etc/init.d/'+COMPs)
```

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but you should use `os.path.join()` rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `/home` isn't mounted when the script runs during boot.

Comment: @Barmar, I thought about /home not being mounted but it's part of the root file system so it'd have to be.

Comment: Does anything update the source files after boot? Print the lengths of the source files.

Comment: pack the code in a try/except block and log the error you maybe will get

Comment: @Barmar. right before I copy the files I do a os.stat to make sure the files are not empty to which they are not.

Comment: @flappix, there would be no error because it does copy the file albeit it's empty.

Comment: Could there be multiple python versions?

Comment: @Barmar, no.  That's not the case here.

Comment: The error could happen after the file is created. Then it would be there but empty.

Comment: @flappix, I see what you're saying.  Let me give that a try.